# Accessing the search bar and searching using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I was trying to access the search bar of this website: https://www.kissanime.ru
using selenium. I tried it using xpath, class, css_selector but every time this error pops up in the terminal.

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: //*[@id="keyword"]

My approach to the problem was :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://kissanime.ru/")
driver.maximize_window()

search=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="keyword"]')
search.send_keys("boruto")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: avoid doing something like this: search=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="keyword"]')  just use find_element_by_id()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding some wait

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "keyword")))
```

Answer (score -1):

**Add wait to avoid race condition**

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```